# Catch Exception without blocking - Spring reactive

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive, spring-webclient

How should I catch the exception without blocking the call (WebClient - SpringReactive)

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> handleWithErrorResumeAndCustomException(ServerRequest request) {
    return ServerResponse.ok()
              .body(sayHello(request)
                .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new NameRequiredException(
                  HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                  "please provide a name", e))), String.class); 
}
```

When an error occurs as part of this call (sayHello), I would like to stop and propagate the exception to the calling function. In the calling function I wants to catch the "NameRequiredException".

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    try{ 
handleWithErrorResumeAndCustomException(request);
    }catch(NameRequiredException e){
     break;
    }
}
```